# SapUI5 odata v4 calling function error "unknown operation"

Tags: httprequest, odata, sapui5, abap

I would like to call a function import with the odata v4 model, but I get an error.
The error message is “Unknown operation:”. I think, “operation” means the kind of http request get or post, or?
My code looks like this:

```
        const dDates = oSelectedDates.map(oDateTemp => oDateTemp.getStartDate());
        var oContext = this.getView().getModel("kddietz").bindContext(`/KddietzTourenplan(${oTourenplan.NId})/CopyTourenplan(...)`);
        oContext.setParameter("dDates", dDates);
        oContext.execute();
```

[image]

My metadata looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Is the path to your function really `https://your.odata.root/KddietzTourenplan(13)/CopyTourenplan(...)`? As far as I know this is only possible for `Action`s. I only ever saw `Function`s on root level: `https://your.odata.root/CopyTourenplan(...)`.

Comment: And is the argument passed to that function literally supposed to be `...`?

Comment: No, that (...) is described in the UI5 docu as a placeholder that is supposed to defer the execution, such that it’s run at the time you want, not immediately upon loading the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem. After one day of debugging, i found out, that sap ui5 needs a namespace for funtion imports and actions. Also if the function is in the default namespace. I can bind the function with "/KddietzTourenplan(${oTourenplan.NId})/Default.CopyTourenplan(...)"